# Capturing 'confidence' value in RASA NLU/CORE

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu

I'm currently training a chatbot to recognize intents and provide fulfillment based on these. It is working fine when the query passed to it resembles what it has been trained on.

However, I'd like to train my chatbot to handle out of scope requests. The idea here is to capture the "confidence" value and use it in an "if/else" statement to provide a standard response if the value is too low.

Is there a way to capture this "confidence" value? Is there a tracker for it similar to slots? See snippet below for confidence value I'm trying to extract.

```
Received user message 'show me Brazilian steak houses'with intent '{'name': 'restaurant_search', 'confidence': 0.4830598338322177}'
```

Answer (score 2):

this is currently not returned as part of the payload, but it is printed if you have logging level set to debug, see https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/4adf5914f25bff9d59dfc1a5492a18e14f7acba7/rasa_core/policies/ensemble.py#L68

we can certainly look into returning that as part of the payload, but possibly your best approach is to create a custom policy which checks this number and overrides it with a fallback action. We should add some documentation on how to do this.

Comment: This would be helpful. Right now I'm just doing it by: `tracker.current_state()` and parsing the dictionary to get the value. But it doesn't always work...